# Fortran compile error on different machine

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm working with a very large piece of mortran code. I'm trying to compile it on my own machine, and the mortran part goes ok, but the fortran compile fails.

On both machines I'm using gfortran with the same flags (`-fPIC`).

Machine 1:

`Linux [omitted] 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 7 01:43:09 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with gfortran 4.1.2 (Working - very old kernel)

Machine 2:

`Linux [omitted] 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with gfortran 5.4.0 (Not working)

The error (most of the time) I'm getting is:

```
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
       ExIN=$ExDEF
            1
```

There's also a few errors about `var has no implicit type`.

I don't have much experience with fortran, but I'd expect compilers to be consistent across platforms, especially since this was developed with the intent of being cross-platform.

Edit - it looks like I had a different version of the mortran compiler. I'm going to try to find the old version and see if that does it. They are mortran macros and they are supposed to expand to something.

Comment: What kind of Fortran flavors do you use? What are the versions of compiler at both machines?

Comment: Not sure what flavors - I did not write the code, `4.1.2` on the working machine and `5.4.0` on the non-working machine

Comment: `$` is not allowed in Fortran tokens. The code is not conforming and certainly was NOT *"developed with the intent of being cross-platform"*. Which compiler options do you use?

Comment: Do you really use **M**ortran?

Comment: Yes, the Makefile builds mortran, and then tries to build fortran. Compiler options are `-fPIC` and `O2` for optimisation

Comment: bite the bullet and go through the code and change the dollar to some unique character string.  I assume its in the original  source code and not something mortran is introducing.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, shouldn't be hard with a sed command. My concern is that it's supposed to be part of a macro or environment variable or something. Possibly supposed to compile through mortran to something?

Answer (score 2):

Dollar is not a valid character of the Fortran character set.

Some compilers allow it by extension. To allow it in GNU Fortran, **but not as first character** and only if the target system supports it, use

```
-fdollar-ok
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Naming-conventions.html

Looks like you are out of luck with this compiler.

You may try g77 with the same option, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.5/g77/Dollar-Signs.html

The old gfortran 4.8.1 also does not speak about the initial letter restriction

> -fdollar-ok
>       Allow `$' as a valid character in a symbol name.

Comment: Tried f77 with the same result. The dollar signs are also present in the code on the working machine, and `-fdollar-ok` is not specified.

Comment: I wrote **g**77 not **f**77. Also, yes, it is quite likely you are out of luck. It is a very nonstandard code. fdollar-ok should be necessary in any case unless Mortran generates something else on the other computer.

Comment: I thought that was a typo. It looks like g77 doesn't exist (it's mentioned in the `ratfor` documentation, but nothing else. [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/g77/G77-and-GCC.html#G77-and-GCC) states it comes with g77, but I don't have a g77 command. Looks like I'm sticking to the old machine unless I can find a very old copy of fortran (that doesn't come on punch cards)

Comment: The thing you are trying is GNU Fortran, not THE Fortran. You are cerainly free to try other compilers. Some are free of charge, some are not. And `g77` certainly DOES exist. If it didn't I wouldn't be writing about it.

Comment: Yes, and I agree that may be worth a shot, but in this case gfortran (and f77 for the record) work on the original machine, so it's not like I'm trying to find what compiler was originally used.

Comment: FWIW ifort allows the `$` even as the first character. You can even use `$` alone as a symbol.  Bizarre.  It is implicitly integer by the way.

Comment: @VladimirF I think it's probably better to say g77 used to exist - it has been superseded by gfortran and hasn't been in development for a decade or more. Yes, the way fortran community works is very conservative and as such there is certainly old, misguided code, that depends on it. But generally I think it better to encourage getting the code working with modern compilers, and avoiding such ancient, long forgotten, extensions. And sorry for teaching you to suck eggs - comments manly for the OP!